# Is Java cross platform?

Tags: java, cross-platform

I want to develop a cross platform application.

Is Java cross platform? I mean, can I develop a Java application in Windows and use it in Mac OS X and Linux?

If yes, how?

**I find application written in Java, has two setup file one for Windows and other for Mac. This confuses me.**

Any illustration or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To be as cross platform as possible use c or c++.

Comment: @Oded C and C++ are definitely *not* cross-platform. You cannot compile and link programs in either of those languages in one OS and expect it to run in another.

Comment: @Oded: I don't think the OP wants to be *"as cross-platform as possible"* as in *"I want to run on every obscure piece of hardware known in existence"*. I think the OP wants to *"as cross-platform as possible"* by having, say, a Swing app running on Windows, OS X and Linux, which would cover 99.9%+ of all the desktop/laptop out there.  Regarding C/C++, what would you suggest to have a "cross-platform GUI" and concurrent libraries? At least Java does offer some kind of a unified GUI and good built-in concurrency libraries **and** amazing tools (I take it you're not familiar with IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r There are enough cross-platform libraries for C++ out there. But I understand your point, too many people are just unable to recompile software for another platform.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> ***Is Java a cross platform?***

Java is cross platform in the sense that a *compiled* Java program runs on all platforms for which there exists a JVM. (This holds for all major operating systems, including Windows, Mac OS and Linux.)

> ***I mean I can develop Java application in windows and use it in mac and Linux?***

**Yes,** this is possible.

This (and the security aspect) is one of the main advantages of running the programs in a virtual machine.

> ***If yes how?***

- Write your application in Java (In `.java` files)
- Compile your application using Eclipse or javac (into `.class` files)
- (Optionally) Bundle your .class files in an executable (`.jar` file)

The very same `.jar` file can be distributed and executed on Windows systems, Mac systems, etc.

> ***I find application written in Java, has two setup file one for windows and other for mac. This confuses me.***

This is because some applications rely on platform-specific features. They are then bundled with different platform-specific libraries.

Unless you're developing an application that itself relies on platform-specific features, (such as for instance low-level system calls), you should be able to do just fine with ordinary Java.

**Important comment** by [@Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey):

> *It can be while the application is platform independent, the setup program is not. e.g. IntelliJ has three platform specific installers which are not written in Java, but have a zip which you can just unzip on any platform and it will work.*

Comment: but I find application written in java , has two setup file one for windows and other for mac , is it strange

Comment: That is just because they may rely on low-level libraries that interact with the operating system in a native way. So unless you're relying on some Linux specific system call etc, you should be just fine with ONE set of class files for every system.

Comment: @AMH, It can be while the application is platform independant, the setup program is not. e.g. IntelliJ has three platform specific installers which are *not written in Java*, but have a zip which you can just unzip on any platform and it will work.

Comment: Even the same java application can be run on different OSs, they depends very much on the JDK/JRE version.

Answer (score 3):

You can run Java applications on every device that has a JVM.  If it does not, you're out of luck.

The comment from Oded is important.  C and C++ have compilers on lots of devices.

Java byte code won't need to be recompiled when you switch platforms.

C and C++ will require that the developer recompile the application before distributing it to the target system, but once that's done clients will be able to run without an issue.

The problem of platform-specific customizations and settings has to be dealt with no matter which language you choose.  The more your application depends on platform-specific features, the less portable it will be.

UPDATE:

Let's revisit the original words in the question:

> I want to develop a cross platform application.

Here's the objective - a direct quote.  No details about web, mobile, or desktop app.

> Is Java cross platform? I mean, can I
>   develop a Java application in Windows
>   and use it in Mac OS X and Linux?

Define "cross platform".  Sounds like the bias here is "byte code portability".  C/C++ can't do that, but "source code portability" is certainly possible as long as you stick to ANSI C/C++ and refrain from using vendor extensions.

Java's claim to fame from the beginning has always been byte code portability.  That's what the JVM gets you.  That does not mean your whole application will be portable, because you might not have managed other dependencies well.

If I substitute "C/C++" for "Java in that bloc, then cross platform means something different.  I cannot pick up a .exe or .so compiled for one platform and expect to run it on another, but if I create an .exe or .so for each platform and make them available it's certainly possible to make the same source code runnable on multiple platforms.

> If yes, how?

If you have packaged your Java app as a JAR, you can put that on any platform you like.

If you have multiple C/C++ .exes for the platforms you're interested in, you can certainly run it when you need to.

Comment: Therefore C and C++ are **not** cross-platform. You cannot expect a user to compile and link source code himself to get a program working.

Comment: I can't expect a user to do it, but I can expect it from a developer who wishes to distribute code to various platforms.  The down votes are not just.  There's nothing incorrect about this answer.

Comment: The language may be cross platform, but a compiled C / C++ application is not. Java is, but as others have said, it's setup is not (like setting JAVA_HOME / making sure Java is in your path etc.).

Comment: That's really the point. A ready-for-use application in C/C++ will only run on the platform it was built to and is therefore by definition *not* cross-platform. Java is, as are other languages like HTML.

Comment: Besides, if I embed that .exe in a VMWare server and share that around, I can run it on any platform that can run VMWare.  The portability argument gets blurry then.  I think we should be talking about current practice and what's possible, not what Bjarne Stroustrup had in mind when he developed C++.

Comment: A lot of programmers use cross-platform and portable interchangeably. This seems to be the source of much of the disagreement in this thread. For instance some people call a library cross-platform when it has been already ported to a lot of systems.

Comment: If there's not a JVM just write your own!  I've done it.

Comment: So helpful nine years late.

Answer (score 2):

There is an important caveat with regard to Java portability.  "Business logic" (non-UI stuff) is quite portable, but there are at least a half-dozen different (and incompatible) user interface paradigms for Java, so, eg, Java code written to run on an Android (even ignoring Android's incompatible JVM) won't run on a Nokia phone, and code for either one will not run on a desktop PC.

But there's no other language that does better, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java written and compiled on one OS can run on another OS. There are JVMs available for many modern operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Java apps are packaged as .jar files. These can run on any operating system that implements the correct Java Runtime Environment for the application, provided the user has installed that JRE (JREs are provided to users for free).

The precise procedure for running the app is different for each operating system.

The Java Development Kit provides libraries that allow system functions (e.g. file operations, user interfaces) to be invoked that ought to work on any OS. However the precise behavior may vary (in a similar way to how a website can look different in different browsers). Also, Java apps may have a 'look and feel' that does not precisely match the look and feel of applications designed specifically for that OS.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "cross-platform".  Java code can be compiled to byte-code binary class or jar files on any OS supporting the JDK and run on any platform supported the JRE.  However, most compiled languages can be compiled on any platform provided the designers has catered for it.  Java is more easily portable than, say, C++, but that doesn't mean C++ code won't be able to compile on any platform.

In other words - don't choose your language on this single feature alone.  Choosing the best language for your application would be a better way of going about it.  Perhaps a scripting language would be best for you.  Maybe post another question asking what language to use to solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little game in Java with sound.
I've used standard library (AudioInputStream and Clip classes).
The program works very good with Windows XP, BUT I haven't got the sounds with Windows Seven or Linux Ubuntu.

Java 6 was installed for all those OS, and I've compiled the program with the standard compiler JAVAC.

So Java is not so "cross platform".

Comment: me too. i was developing a water mark app that used graphics standard lib that compile with jdk 7 on linux .but it did`nt work on ms windows.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA is not really cross-platform because is just a design, some JAVA implementations can be cross-platform but it really depends on the JAVA implementer.

SUN/Oracle makes the JAVA standard implementation for Windows, MAC and Linux and if you build programs with their JDK you should run the programs with their JRE, if you try to run it with other JRE there might be compatibility issues.

This can be seen more in the mobile, some phone makers won't make a full implementation of JAVA because hardware limitations or because they want to control the device's software, they carry the JAVA logo but you must use their own JDK and those programs could not run outside of their JVM implementation.

Another issue with JAVA is that some functionality could be deprecated and what ran in some specific version of the JRE could not run in newer versions or run in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is when we are talking about mobile apps. For desktops OS, java can run perfectly, but for mobile devices, developers can, practically, only create for Android. There are tools like [Totalcross](http://www.totalcross.com) that helps java developers to create apps to iOS and Android. The focus is maintain the WORA assumption to every platform, even mobile.