# Creating Desktop Application using Netbeans or Eclispse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I want to create a desktop application for windows. Can i use Netbeans or Eclipse to create a java based desktop application for windows?

Comment: on mac or on windows ?

Comment: Of course.  Your IDE has little to do with what you produce and everything to do with how.  You should prefer IntelliJ by JetBrains to both of those.  It's the best IDE on the market.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java cross platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978005/is-java-cross-platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are developing a java application, you won't compile for specific systems or machines. You will compile for a java virtual machine(JVM) only. Thus, you can create your app from mac, windows, linux or unix and it will work on all other systems that has a JVM on it.

You can read more on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978036/4438220).

Answer (score 1):

Both Netbeans and Eclipse are good platforms for creating Desktop Applications.But netbeans is more easier to understand according to me.