# How to make sure my *jar or *class will run on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu

Sorry if this is off-topic. I am a java beginner and know java is supposed to be cross-platform consistent. But I wonder if the fact that my jar file or *class file executes on Ubuntu guarantees it will run fine on MacOS?

I basically do the following to create *class and *jar. Two java classes, `MAIN.java` depends on `SIDE.java` and both java files include `package classes;` header (`javac` creates a folder named `classes` and puts `MAIN.class` and `SIDE.class` in there):

```
javac -d . SIDE.java MAIN.java
jar cvfe MAIN.jar classes/MAIN classes/*.class
```

I tried running both:

```
java classes.MAIN -read number.logs
```

and

```
java -jar MAIN.jar -read number.logs
```

and they both run fine on Ubuntu. Is this good enough and it will run on MacOS? (I don't have MacOS, is there a simulator that I could use in this case to check things?)

Comment: A good question. I've encountered several application that works great on Ubuntu and Windows but fails to work in MacOS, like Robot class. It's best to test in all platforms before releasing the application to public.

Comment: Define "run fine". I would have thought that many of the potential problems you could have would be differences in environmental variables (etc), rather than Ubuntu Vs Mac specifically. For instance, can it run with different locale, timezone, line separator even.

Comment: @AndyTurner takes the inputs and generates the expected output.

Comment: @Dorado, but is there a MacOS simulator to use?

Comment: for simulator, you can use any virtual machine.

Comment: @user3639557 I'm fortunate for my wife to own a MacBook, my work provides MacBook. My personal computer is a Windows 10, and I installed a VM with Ubuntu image. There are some ways to do this. A suggestion, you could bring USB to a Apple Store and try on their demo MacBook, ask a friend to borrow MacBook, or at the least buy a MacOS image. MacOS is difficult to obtain for no cost.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is good enough until and unless you use some environment variables i.e. platform specific features like 
`System.getProperty("os.name")`.

This cross platform portability is ensured by JVM. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978005/is-java-cross-platform).

Answer (score 1):

Java is cross-platform for a reason. Your java code is translated into a java bytecode (your `.class` files) and the [`JVM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) (Java Virtual Machine) is a machine which is running your bytecode.

This JVM comes with the Java installation on your operating system. Thus if you can install the JRE (which includes the JVM) you can run your code.

There is one exception, the Java language sometimes uses os-standards for representation of graphics (awt classes), so your program, if you are using those classes, can look different, but work the same.

How, for example, an operating system is saving files, is handled by the JVM and shouldn't concern you as a high-level developer unless you are running into restrictions from the OS-Side. Those restrictions are, depending on the case, handled by Exceptions. If you handle exceptions in your code, there is little to nothing that will not work on one os if it worked on another.